# Get Maximum value of a cluster as a constraint in a MILP

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, clustering

I am facing the following problem:
I have same kind of a clustering Problem

\begin{alignat}{4}
 \text{min }\quad& \sum_{c \in C} \sum_{s \in S} - y_{c,s}\\[2ex]
 \text{s.t. }\quad& \sum_{c \in C}\sum_{s \in S} x_{p,c,s}  &= &\quad 1        &\quad\forall p \in P \\
 & y_{c,s}                 &\le &\quad x_{p,c,s} \cdot S_{p,c,s}      &\quad \forall p \in P, \forall c \in C, \forall s \in S \\
 & x_{p,c,s}             &\in &\quad \{0,1\}      &\quad\forall p \in P, \forall c \in C, \forall s \in S \\
 & y_{c,s}              &\in &\quad \mathbb{R}^+    &\quad\forall c \in C, \forall s \in S \\
\end{alignat}

$y_{c,s}$ should indicate the maximum of all every Parameter $p$ multiplied with a factor $S_{p,c,s}$ which are assignt to cluster $(c,s)$. Normally I would use $y_{c,s} \ge x_{p,c,s} \cdot S_{p,c,s}$ but due to the fact I want to maximize the maximum value in every cluster $(c,s)$ the variable $y_{c,s}$ would be choosen infinit.
I kind find at the moment a good idea to solve this problem, I also already thought about the big-$M$ Methode but I couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

Thanks in advance for your help

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to maximize $$\sum_c \sum_s \max_{p: x_{pcs}=1} S_{pcs},$$ and you have introduced $y_{cs}$ to represent the summand $\max_{p: x_{pcs}=1} S_{pcs}$.  Introduce binary variable $z_{pcs}$ to indicate whether $y_{cs}=S_{pcs}$.  The constraints are
\begin{align}
\sum_p z_{pcs} &= 1 &&\text{for all $c,s$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_p S_{pcs} z_{pcs} &= y_{cs} &&\text{for all $c,s$} \tag2 \\
z_{pcs} &\le x_{pcs} &&\text{for all $p,c,s$} \tag3
\end{align}
If cluster $(c,s)$ can be empty, relax constraint $\eqref{1}$ to $\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works for me :)